# Why some operators are not working as expected with recordsets in Odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, operator-overloading, odoo-8, odoo, recordset

I have done some tests:

```py
>>> empty_recordset = self.env['res.users']                                 # empty recordset
>>> not_empty_recordset = self.env['res.users'].search([('id', '=', 1)])    # recordset with one record

>>> empty_recordset is False
False

>>> empty_recordset is None
False

>>> empty_recordset == False
False

>>> empty_recordset == True
False

>>> bool(empty_recordset)
False

>>> not empty_recordset
True

>>> if empty_recordset:           # it is treated as False
...     print('hello')
... 

>>> bool(not_empty_recordset)
True

>>> if not_empty_recordset:
...     print('hello')
... 
hello

>>> not not_empty_recordset
False
```

- When the recordset is cast with `bool()` it returns `True` or `False`.
- With `if` and `not` statements the result is the expected as well.
- But when it is used with the operators `is`, `==`, `!=` the result is not the expected.

What is happening? Is the recordset treated as a boolean value only with the `if` and `not` statements? Are the rest of the operators not overloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the way [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) is implemented:

> Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation bool(); should return False or True, or their integer equivalents 0 or 1. When this method is not defined, **len**() is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither **len**() nor **nonzero**(), all its instances are considered true.

You can check it on [odoo/odoo/models.py](https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/10.0/odoo/models.py#L5068):

For Odoo 10 the code is:

```py
def __nonzero__(self):
    """ Test whether ``self`` is nonempty. """
    return bool(getattr(self, '_ids', True))
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Lucas answer that explain all.  in python all operation are converted to method calls

```
      if object: 
       #  is turned to. 
      if object.__nonzero__():
```

And

```
      if object == value:
      #is turned to
      if object.__eq__(value):
```

even this is:

```
      object + value
      # is converted go this
      object.__add__(value)
```

All operators have there matching methods.

And this why you got different result when you changed the operator, because python calls under the hood a different method.